# Range matching to return value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble finding the solution to this one. It'd usually be a `merge()` to attain something similar but I can't find if it'd be extra tacked on

Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

num = {'serial':[10,20,30,50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(num)
cols = {'StartSerial':[9,19,29,39],'StopSerial':[15,25,35,45],'Job':[564,859,748,125]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(cols)
```

Trying to do something similar to this, but its not possible due to the indices not matching:

```
df['Job'] = np.where((df['serial'] >= df2['StartSerial']) & (df['serial'] <= df2['StopSerial']),df2['Job'],'')
```

This does not work either:

```
df.loc[(df['serial'] >= df2['StartSerial']) & (df['serial'] <= df2['StopSerial']),Job] = df2['Job']
```

Desired output:

```
serial | Job
------------
10     | 564

20     | 859

30     | 748

50     |
```

Comment: Please provide your desired results, as per this help page; [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create `pd.IntervalIndex` and then use this index to find the right values:

```py
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2.StartSerial, df2.StopSerial, closed="both")
good_keys = df2.index.intersection(idx.get_indexer(df.serial))

df["job"] = df2.loc[good_keys, "Job"]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   serial    job
0      10  564.0
1      20  859.0
2      30  748.0
3      50    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# links each row of df to all rows of df2
df = df.merge(df2, how='cross')
#
    serial  StartSerial  StopSerial  Job
0       10            9          15  564
1       10           19          25  859
2       10           29          35  748
3       10           39          45  125
4       20            9          15  564
5       20           19          25  859
6       20           29          35  748
7       20           39          45  125
8       30            9          15  564
9       30           19          25  859
10      30           29          35  748
11      30           39          45  125
12      50            9          15  564
13      50           19          25  859
14      50           29          35  748
15      50           39          45  125
#
df['Job'] = np.where((df['serial'] >= df['StartSerial']) & (df['serial'] <= df['StopSerial']),df['Job'],np.NaN)
# the tricky part is here, since a sum will transform NaNs into 0 which is not desirable
df.groupby("serial",as_index=False)["Job"].sum().replace({0.0: np.NaN})
#
   serial    Job
0      10  564.0
1      20  859.0
2      30  748.0
3      50    NaN
```

Other solutions do exist.

The easier to understand solution is to transform the Start and Stop into values and fill them in.

```
df2["serial"] = df2.apply(lambda x: [*range(x["StartSerial"], x["StopSerial"]+1)], axis=1)
#
   StartSerial  StopSerial  Job                        serial
0            9          15  564   [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
1           19          25  859  [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
2           29          35  748  [29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
3           39          45  125  [39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45]
#
df2 = df2.explode("serial")[["Job","serial"]].reset_index(drop=True)
#
    Job serial
0   564      9
1   564     10
2   564     11
3   564     12
4   564     13
5   564     14
6   564     15
7   859     19
8   859     20
9   859     21
10  859     22
11  859     23
12  859     24
13  859     25
14  748     29
15  748     30
16  748     31
17  748     32
18  748     33
19  748     34
20  748     35
21  125     39
22  125     40
23  125     41
24  125     42
25  125     43
26  125     44
27  125     45
#
df.merge(df2, how="left", )
```